# Wordpress/PHP How to display a string value in an array into a <li>

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting an array of data from a wordpress custom field with this code:

```
<?php 
$values = get_field('google_location');
if($value) {
foreach($values as $value) {
echo $value;
}
}
?>
```

and here is the output from the array:

```
array(2) { ["coordinates"]=> string(22) "38.9974266,-77.1104762" ["address"]=> string(48) "8600 Old Georgetown Rd, Bethesda, Maryland 20814" }

array(2) { ["coordinates"]=> string(29) "37.7911347,-79.88268779999999" ["address"]=> string(26) "Arh Ln, Low Moor, VA 24457" }

array(2) { ["coordinates"]=> string(21) "38.9010559,-77.050792" ["address"]=> string(36) "900 23rd St NW, Washington, DC 20037" }
```

how do I grab the coordinates (long, lat) in these arrays from the string and insert them into li items.  I want my HTML to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>38.9974266,-77.1104762</li>
    <li>37.7911347,-79.88268779999999</li>
    <li>38.9010559,-77.050792</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: the dump you have posted is `$values`? In your foreach loop, just get `$value['coordinates']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $value is pretty much all the data you're getting. Because you just want to coordinates you'll have something like this:

```
    <ul>
            <?php 
        $values = get_field('google_location');
        if($values) {
        foreach($values as $value) {
 echo  '<li>'. $value["coordinates"] .'</li>';
         }
        }
        ?>
</ul>
```

This should work. I didn't check it, but it should work

Comment: Should be `if ($values)` rather than `if ($value)`.

Comment: when I use $value["coordinates"] for only the coordinates, I get an error

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way:

```
$values = get_field('google_location');
echo "<ul><li>" . implode( '</li><li>', $values) . "</li></ul>";
```